# sqlite3.rb:6:in require: libruby.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

sorry for my english.
I was learning about ruby on rails and i tried to update to rails 5.
I uninstall olders version of ruby and now i have problems.

i have reading http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

i made a mistake because i uninstalled something that i dint do.
now i have  ruby-2.3.1

i have this error now.

> .gem/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require':
>   libruby.so.2.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory -
>   /home/yvasquez/.gem/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.so
>   (LoadError)

Thanks for reply

Comment: I am using Linux 3.16.0-4-586 #1 Debian 3.16.36-1 (2016-07-04) i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with ruby 2.3 & 2.3.1. It is because it fails to recognize the devkit (which i hope you need not install unless you're using Windows) gems as native ruby gems. The problem is with the latest ruby version and the gem configs located in the directory, where you will have to manually specify the native part to each gem.

Anyway, I went back to ruby 2.2.5, and everything works perfectly for me.
Try ruby 2.2.5 OR since you are on linux, try re installing and make sure you add everything to the path so your gems are recognized. Also, try installing sqlite3 separately and add to path.